# Convert xml to csv in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which plugins or gems are available to convert xml to csv file ?

Comment: XML has a far richer structure than CSV. How exactly do you expect a generic conversion to be done? Or are you looking for something to convert a particular XML to CSV?

Comment: There is no 1:1 mapping between XML and CSV, as XML is a tree and CSV is a spreadsheet. You will have to be more specific in terms of what kind of XML you are trying to transform.

Comment: You may want to look at ruby-toolbox.com to see which gem/plugin is best suited to your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the two formats generally have nothing to do with each other, I would suggest parsing the XML with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and then building up your CSV with [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/). You need to provide the logic in between to decide which parts go where in your CSV file.

Comment: an example would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Using Nokogiri in Rails.

```
 xml_file = "datafile.xml"
 doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_file)
 output = "data.csv"

 sv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  # header row
     csv << ['header_array']

  # data rows
    @object_array.map do |object|
      csv << [object['NODE_NAME'].text]
    end
  end

 #send response  

   send_data csv_string,
          :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
          :disposition => "attachment; filename=users.csv"
```